# How would go about selecting rows from a MySQL database into JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm still learning java and was wondering how could I implement selecting rows from a MySQL database into a JTable. I've been stuck on this for a day now and am asking for any help. I tried other methods on here but still got stuck. I pasted my code below:

```
package src;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FishApp extends JFrame {
    
    FishApp() throws ClassNotFoundException {
  //Create the frame
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fishing Log Application");
  //Create label
  JLabel tab1Label = new JLabel("Log a fish you caught!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
  JLabel tab2Label = new JLabel("This is a directory of all the recorded catches.", SwingConstants.CENTER);
  JLabel tab3label = new JLabel("<html>I developed this application in order for fisherman like you and me<br/> to be able to log their catches and note down additional info of their trip. <br/>This application was created by Brendan Dill in 2022. <br/>Any questions or concerns contact here <a href='brdxn.github.io'>here</a></html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
  JLabel speciesLabel = new JLabel("Species: ");
  JLabel lengthLabel = new JLabel("Length (inches): ");
  JLabel weightLabel = new JLabel("Weight (pounds): ");
  JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel("Date caught: ");
  JLabel locationLabel = new JLabel("Location caught: ");
  JLabel additionalLabel = new JLabel("Additional Info: ");


  //Create panel 1
  JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

  //Create fields for panel 1
  JTextField speciesField = new JTextField("common name format",20);
  JTextField lengthField = new JTextField(5);
  JTextField weightField = new JTextField(6);
  JTextField dateField = new JTextField("mm-dd-yyyy format", 10);
  JTextField locationField = new JTextField("place, city, state format", 30);
  JTextArea additionalField = new JTextArea();

  //Get text from field
  Random id = new Random();  
  int fishID = id.nextInt(1000);


  //Create log button
  JButton logBtn = new JButton("Log catch!");

  //Create load button
  JButton loadBtn = new JButton("Load catches...");
  loadBtn.setBounds(50,50,50,30);

  //Create table
 /*  String data[][]={ {"1","Flounder","21","5","9/18/22","Ocean","Chartruse Bucktail"}};    
  String column[]={"FishId","Species","Length", "Weight", "Date", "Location", "Additional Info"};         
  JTable fishTable=new JTable(data,column);    
  fishTable.setBounds(30,40,200,600);          
  JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(fishTable);    */

  

  //Set the layout for panel 1
  p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
  //Add label in panel 1
  p1.add(tab1Label);
  p1.add(speciesLabel);
  p1.add(speciesField);
  p1.add(lengthLabel);
  p1.add(lengthField);
  p1.add(weightLabel);
  p1.add(weightField);
  p1.add(dateLabel);
  p1.add(dateField);
  p1.add(locationLabel);
  p1.add(locationField);
  p1.add(additionalLabel);
  p1.add(additionalField);
  p1.add(logBtn);

  //Create panel 2
  JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
  p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
  p2.add(tab2Label);
  //p2.add(sp);
  p2.add(loadBtn);
  //Create panel 3
  JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
  p3.add(tab3label);

  
  //Create the tab container
  JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
  //Set tab container position
  tabs.setBounds(20,20,750,750);
  //Associate each panel with the corresponding tab
  tabs.add("Log Fish", p1);
  tabs.add("Directory", p2);
  tabs.add("About", p3);
  
  //Add tabs to the frame
  frame.add(tabs);
  
  frame.setSize(800,800);
  frame.setLayout(null);
  frame.setVisible(true);


  //Log catch into database 
    logBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String species = speciesField.getText();
            String length = lengthField.getText();
            String weight = weightField.getText();
            String date = dateField.getText();
            String location = locationField.getText();
            String additional = additionalField.getText();


           try {Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sys","root","");
// Insert query shouldn't have *
            String query = "INSERT INTO `FishEntry` (FishId, Species, Length, Weight, Date, Location, AdditionalInfo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
             preparedStmt.setInt (1, fishID);
             preparedStmt.setString(2, species);
             preparedStmt.setString(3, length);
             preparedStmt.setString(4, weight);
             preparedStmt.setString(5, date);
             preparedStmt.setString(6, location);
             preparedStmt.setString(7, additional);
             preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        }
            catch (Exception d) {
            System.out.println("Error found "+ d);
        }

        
    }
    });

    //Load Catches from MySQL database
    loadBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sys","root","");
            String query = "SELECT * FROM FishEntry;";
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStmt.executeQuery(query);

            int i = 0; 

            String data[][]= new String[8][7];    
            String column[]={"FishId","Species","Length", "Weight", "Date", "Location", "Additional Info"};         
            JTable fishTable=new JTable(data,column);    
            fishTable.setBounds(30,40,200,600);          
            JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(fishTable);

            while(rs.next()) {
                int fishId2 = rs.getInt("FishId");
                String species2 = rs.getString("Species");
                String length2 = rs.getString("Length");
                String weight2 = rs.getString("Weight");
                String date2 = rs.getString("Date");
                String location2 = rs.getString("Location");
                String additional2 = rs.getString("AdditionalInfo");

                data[i][0] = fishId2 + "";
                data[i][1] = species2;
                data[i][2] = length2;
                data[i][3] = weight2;
                data[i][4] = date2;
                data[i][5] = location2;
                data[i][6] = additional2;
                i++;
            }

 
            p2.add(sp);
        }
            catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException d) {
            System.out.println("Error found "+ d);
        }
            
        }

    });

 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException 
 {
  new FishApp();
 }
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Example of where I want to put the JTable:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axyz3.png]

Comment: Easiest solution is to create an empty JTable and add it to the scroll pane. Then add the scroll pane to the frame. When you want to change the data you just create a new DefaultTableModel and then use the `setModel(...)` method of the JTable to update the data. Also, don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: @camickr, Thank you I finally got it!